# Commenting broken?

Tags: bug, comments, error-message

Is it just me or is writing or editing comments broken?

It either takes forever or it shows an error or a (pretty cute) dead robot..:

[image]

For a while it seemed as if it only happens when submitting with the Enter key but now also dies when clicking the Save Edits button..

Update: Atm refreshing pages also doesn't work, so are alien robots attacking SO??

Comment: even some questions don't open up? I get the same page. Its happening since almost an hour now

Comment: Main site is totally down for me in UK

Comment: Happened to me last week as well, cleared up in about 15 minutes.

Comment: Whole site is unreachable every few minutes for me. Works again after a few minutes, but does not show any maintenance messages.

Comment: Just got it to work again..

Comment: The whole SE network has connectivity issues right now when trying to reach it from Europe. At least that's what I am experiencing. long loading times, sometimes error pages.

Comment: Seems ok for me now.

Comment: It is still flaky, sometimes getting "an error occurred" when voting on a post.  Refresh the page, vote again, no error.

Comment: Had this issue last week, I guess SE is updating some of their servers which lead to higher response times on the remaining servers, which now have to pack a bigger bunch of requests.